# creating ability objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when choosing a character I currently have a base class

```
abstract class CharacterClass
    {
        public abstract void AbilityOne();

        public abstract void AbilityTwo();
    }
```

And my characters derive from this class

```
class Warrior : CharacterClass
{
    public override void AbilityOne()
    {
        // implement ability one here
    }

    public override void AbilityTwo()
    {
        // implement ability two here
    }
}
```

Lastly I use this code to select the Warrior

```
CharacterClass selectedClass = new Warrior(); // start the game as a Warrior
```

So this way works pretty fine. But when it comes to cooldowns etc. I want to stay with a clean code so I thought about creating a `Ability` class.

My abstract parent class

```
abstract class CharacterClass
{
    public Ability AbilityOne { get; set; }

    public Ability AbilityTwo { get; set; }
}
```

The Warrior class

```
class Warrior : CharacterClass
{
    public Warrior()
    {
        // Set the new Abilities
        AbilityOne = new Ability(3, Smash()); // pass in the method as a parameter ??
        AbilityTwo = new Ability(7, Shieldblock());
    }

            private void Smash()
    {
        // Ability 1
    }

    private void ShieldBlock()
    {
        // Ability 2
    }
}
```

And my skill class

```
class Ability
    {
        public Ability(int cooldown, [the ability method here])
        {
            CoolDown = cooldown;
            TheAbility = ? the ability parameter ?
        }

        public int CoolDown { get; set; }

        public void TheAbility(){}
    }
```

So the warrior will pass in his two skills and creates two ability objects. In the game I could write

```
CharacterClass selectedClass = new Warrior();
selectedClass.AbilityOne();
```

and this would result into a smash with a cooldown of 3 seconds. Is this possible to implement .. somehow .. ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking into Unity's ScriptableObjects for this kind of stuff. I did and never looked back. Standard classes and monobehaviours don't quite provide the correct fit for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
class Ability
{
    public Ability(int cooldown, Action ab)
    {
        CoolDown = cooldown;
        TheAbility = ab;
    }

    public int CoolDown { get; set; }

    public Action TheAbility;
}


class Warrior : CharacterClass
{
    public Warrior()
    {
        // Set the new Abilities
        AbilityOne = new Ability(3, Smash);
        AbilityTwo = new Ability(7, ShieldBlock);

        AbilityOne.TheAbility(); // Will run Smash() method
    }

    private void Smash()
    {
        // Ability 1
    }

    private void ShieldBlock()
    {
        // Ability 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `AbilityOne` returns an `Ability` object it would make sense to create the infrastructure within the `Ability` class that handles different logic that an ability might have, e.g. running the clock on the cooldown timer in some `Update()` method, using the ability, etc.

So the code for calling your ability would look something like:

```
selectedClass.AbilityOne.Trigger();
```

It would also make sense to store the ability method as a `System.Action` within your ability class.

```
class Ability
{
    public Ability(int cooldown, System.Action _abilityMethod)
    {
        CoolDown = cooldown;
        abilityMethod = _abilityMethod;
    }

    public int CoolDown { get; set; }

    public void Trigger()
    {
        if( abilityMethod != null )
        {
            abilityMethod();
        }
    }

    private System.Action abilityMethod;
}
```